# How do I stop hover effect from briefly showing original color?

Tags: html, css

When I hover over my visited links the original `a` green color is briefly shown before it transitions to the `a:hover` color, and when I hover off it transitions to the `a` color before it snaps to the `a:visited` color. Same issue when I test `a:active`. I want it to transition between all colors smoothly and not transition to the `a` color before snapping to the correct color.

My CSS:

```
a {
    background-color: green;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 200ms;
    will-change: all;
}
a:visited {
    background-color: #5dca48;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}

a:active {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can [reproduce your problem](https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/GRGKbRP), in Firefox, but I don't have a solution.

**Note for users:** You need to click the link in the example once to make it "visited", and then you will see the darker green color before it turns yellow on hovering over it.

Using Windows 11, it does happen in Firefox, but not in Chrome or Edge. I would call this a *"feature"* of Firefox, if I'm being nice, or a *"bug"*, if I'm being harsh. I cannot find a bug report for this.

The "cause" is this property:

```
transition: all 200ms;
```

One possible solution would be to forget about the `:visited` styling or the slow transition. I know, not the best solution, but I don't see a way to work around this unless I introduce some Javascript.